# Is a matrix over a PID similar to its transpose?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, principal-ideal-domains, transpose

We say that two matrices $A,\,B\in M_n(R)$ are similar if there is some invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=B$. Now, if $R$ was a field (or certainly an algebraically closed field) then it is straightforward to show $A$ and $A^T$ are similar. Simply use the Jordan form.

> I am wondering if this result also holds true over more general rings, say a PID.

As a starting position I was thinking of looking over $\mathbb{Z}$ and perhaps using the Smith Normal Form in some way.

Comment: The Smith normal form produces representatives for  equivalence classes of matrices over PID under an equivalence relation that is different from the similarity relation. So your strategy of proof is bound to fail. In fact, as the example below shows, this is false.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not!

The matrix $A=\pmatrix{8&2\\0&1}$ is not similar over $\mathbb Z$ to its transpose.

Comment: Why these two are not similar?

Answer (score 2):

For another example, the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is not similar over $\mathbb{Z}$ to its transpose.

(I've just checked this, as I wondered whether assuming unitriangularity would help.)